# Get an intent from onReceive() method

Tags: android, android-intent, onresume, android-broadcastreceiver

I want to send intent from `onReceive()` method to `onResume()` method.

In my opinion, It was OK to send from `onReceive()` to `onResume()`.

However, In `onResume()` method.

```
Intent intent_Main = getIntent();
String getmsg = intent_Main.getExtras().getString("states");
textView.setText("Broadcast message received:"+getmsg);
```

If i use `intent_Main.getExtras().getString("states");` statement, the application was stopped.

What is the problem?

I think that there is no problem in `BroadcastReceiver` or transmit intent.

Logcat,

```
11-11 02:13:39.268 2666-2666/com.example.wonheelee.simplereceiver E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                Process: com.example.wonheelee.simplereceiver, PID: 2666
                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.wonheelee.simplereceiver/com.example.wonheelee.simplereceiver.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                    at com.example.wonheelee.simplereceiver.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:45)
                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1258)
                    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6312)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3092)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134) 
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481) 
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Post the logcat output from the crash and your `onReceive()` method of your `BroadcastReceiver`

Comment: I think the problem on the logcat is
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference at com.example.wonheelee.simplereceiver.MainActivity.onResume. However i don't know how to handle